# How would I combine 2 distinct tables into 1 table in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Say I have 2 distinct tables in SSIS from 2 different servers.

```
Table 1                             Table 2

Animal  Age                      Owner     Location


Dog    10                        Bill       IL
Dog     7                        Kelly      CA
Cat     4                        Tom        TX
```

I want to have one single result table that is

```
Result Table

Animal  Age  Owner     Location


Dog     10   NULL      NULL
Dog     7    NULL      NULL
Cat     4    NULL      NULL
NULL    NULL Bill      IL
NULL    NULL Kelly     CA
NULL    NULL Tom       TX
```

Comment: How do  you know which animal belongs to which owner?

Comment: How do you join those tables?

Comment: I'm sorry I screwed up the result table. They should be individual records with those values null

Comment: So, does *Bill* own *Dog(10)* ?

Comment: No they are all independent from each other

Answer (score 1):

a `UNION` should fit:

```
select animal, age, null as owner, null as location from animal
union
select null as animal, null as age, owner, location from owner
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use merge component from SSIS tools. If you want FULL OUTER JOIN you will choose that in the editor of component.

[image]

But first of all you need to go to the **Input and Output Properties** tab and in the **OLE DB Source** Output set the **IsSorted** property value to *True*.(You need to make sure that the input data is truly sorted though.)

Comment: What would be my join key? I don't want to join to anything, I want distinct rows that include all those columns?

Comment: This approach was building in SSIS and give you result. All that you need to identify two column with not overlap data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **join** two datasets without any join logic (No key in common) you need to:

- Create a fake key column **in each dataset** (With derived column for exemple, value of the fake column should be different in each dataset)
- Sort these fake key columns
- Use a full outer join merge based on these fake relations

You make think it's a weird way to do, that is because it's a weird result you are trying to obtain, maybe could you explain your initial need ?

Comment: The need is that I have 2 tables. 1 Table with 20 columns and the 2nd table had 10 columns. There are 3-4 similar columns between both the tables, BUT THEY ARE NOT USED FOR JOINING. I want to end up with a table that had 26 columns(combining the columns that overlap but still having distinct rows, the values that don't overlap would be null)

Comment: So you can user the fake join column to do the job. But you know in relational model we don't put potatoes with tomatoes in the same table.